# Make interactive CLI interfaces in node.js

Tags: node.js, command-line, interface, command-line-interface

How would you make a interactive CLI interface in node? I'm hoping something like create-svelte-app is possible to recreate.

(GIF for anyone who isn't familiar with svelte's)[image]

Comment: Why don't you get an eye there ? https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte

Comment: @GillesQuénot Probably want to link the actual CLI, not Svelte itself: https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/tree/master/packages/kit and https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/tree/master/packages/create-svelte

Comment: I'm not sure which part of it covers the interface though. cli.js is just command-line arguments.